# Surface integral of vector field over cone, vertex not at origin

Tags: mathematical-physics, coordinate-systems, mathematics

I have a vector field (originally given in Cartesian form). I need to find its integral over a cone with equation something like:$$1-z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, z>0$$

How do I proceed? It is not possible in spherical coordinates as vertex is not at origin.

Comment: This seems like a question that belongs more to math.se?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get an answer there. Please see if you can help me

Comment: Find two parameters that nicely parameterize the 2D surface of the cone, just as $\theta$ and $\phi$ parameterize the surface of a sphere. (Need a hint? See (17)-(19) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cone.html) and make a minor adjustment for the apex not being at the origin.) Then compute the area element $dA$ in those coordinates.

Comment: I note you only waited 5 hours for an answer on Mathematics SE before posting here.  That's simply not long enough.  And if you do not get an answer you should consider *editing* the original question to add more details (and some indication of your own efforts.  A more complete mathematical expression of the problem would be better - don't expect people to guess exactly what you want as this is a real turn off for readers.